# Как удалить всю строку из входного файла использую данные лишь из одного столбца?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно удалить данные всей строки, используя данные столбца "idsot".
У меня есть код для парсинга файла, использовал DictReader.

```
import csv
file = open('sotrudnikii.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
read = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
manager = sorted(read, key=lambda x: int(x['idsot']), reverse=False)
```

Comment: к примеру, мы вводим интересующий id сотрудника, и после этого удаляется вся строка в файле.

Comment: используйте модуль pandas для обработки табличных данных